# Erro ao tentar imprimir uma matriz com maiores elementos de outras duas matrizes - 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, matriz

No meu código,eu crio duas matrizes,e comparo os elementos das duas em cada posição. O elemento maior em cada posição,é selecionado e colocado na terceira matriz. Ao terminar toda a verificação,tenho o loop para imprimir a terceira matriz,porém,recebo o erro de
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable - na linha de código da impressão do loop:

```
for i in range(4):
    print(m3[i])
```

Meu código completo abaixo:

```
m1 = []
m2 = []
m3 = []

for i in range(4):
    linha = []
    for j in range(4):
        linha.append(int(input('Primeira Matriz - Insira o valor ['+ str(i) +','+ str(j) +']:')))
    m1.append(linha)
for i in range(4):
    linha = []
    for j in range(4):
        linha.append(int(input('Segunda Matriz - Insira o valor ['+ str(i) +','+ str(j) +']:')))
    m2.append(linha)
maior = 0
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
         if m1[i][j] > m2[i][j]:
             m3 = m1[i][j]
         else:
            m3 = m2[i][j]
for i in range(4):
    print(m3[i])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você faz `m3 = m1[i][j]`, a variável `m3` está recebendo um número. Ou seja, ela não é mais uma lista, e portanto ela não tem posições a serem acessadas. Daí o erro "*'int' object is not subscriptable*", pois fazer `m3[i]` quando `m3` é um número não funciona.

O que você precisa fazer é ir adicionando as linhas e colunas em `m3`:

```
m3 = []
for i in range(4):
    linha = []
    for j in range(4):
         if m1[i][j] > m2[i][j]:
             linha.append(m1[i][j])
         else:
             linha.append(m2[i][j])
    m3.append(linha)
```

Se bem que você pode percorrer `m1` e `m2` ao mesmo tempo usando [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), e usar [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) para obter o maior dos elementos:

```
m3 = []
for linha1, linha2 in zip(m1, m2):
    linha = []
    for e1, e2 in zip(linha1, linha2):
        linha.append(max(e1, e2))
    m3.append(linha)
```

A cada iteração, `linha1` é uma das linhas de `m1` e `linha2` é uma das linhas de `m2`. Depois, eu percorro essas linhas ao mesmo tempo (também usando `zip`, assim a cada iteração, `e1` é um elemento da `linha1` e `e2` é um elemento da `linha2`) e adiciono o maior dentre esses elementos na linha.

O *loop* acima também pode substituído por uma [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](/q/192343/112052):

```
m3 = [
   [ max(e1, e2) for e1, e2 in zip(linha1, linha2) ]
   for linha1, linha2 in zip(m1, m2)
]
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda,corrigi e funcionou perfeitamente